# Samsung Note II device Driver

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2

When I plug my phone (Samsung Note II) into my Laptop only charging takes place. I cannot view my phone in My Computer. When I go to Device Manager, it says the Driver for GT- N7100 not installed. Install the latest driver for the device”.

When I run trouble shooting a window appears saying GT-N7100 does not have a driver.

What should I do to resolve this problem? However, it was working very well during last 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [Samsung Smart Switch](http://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/) or [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/app/kies) will definitely give you the drivers you need, without needing to install any drivers from Shady sites.